# Get table inside a div container

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to get a table inside a div this is what it looks like in html structure

```
<div class="table_container">
  <table id="main_table">
  </table>
</div>

let pageContent = await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName("table_container")[0].getElementsByTagName("table")[0].innerHTML);
```

but this is not working. What's wrong with my code

Comment: Your code is working by itself. The issue may be in the broader context. For example, check if the elements are loaded (see [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options)).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is "correct", so I will try to explain what is happening here, hope this help you. Looking to your selector:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("table_container")[0].getElementsByTagName("table")[0].innerHTML
```

```html
<div class="table_container">
  <table id="main_table">#
##</table>
</div>
```

The result of this will be a string with some spaces (marked as **#**), or even nothing if the html not have spaces between tags. You are getting this result because you get the first `div.table_container` and then you get the table at index `[0]` and then the `innerHTML` of a empty table. You can add some content to table to retrieve a more "concrete" result, like adding a body to table:

```html
<div class="table_container">
  <table id="main_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

#### Result

```html
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

#### Puppeteer code

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async function() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("http://localhost:5000"); // used a simple npx serve with a static html file

    const content = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.getElementsByClassName("table_container")[0].getElementsByTagName("table")[0].innerHTML;
    });

    console.log(content);
    await browser.close();
})();
```